# SSIS connection manager in VS 2008 throw "Invalid authorization specification Invalid connection string attribute.”

Tags: visual-studio-2008, authentication, ssis, passwords, sql-server-2012

In **SSIS Visual Studio 2008 Project**, when I put a password with equals symbol (**=**) in Connection Manager to connect to my **SQL Server 2012** database, for example my password is **=naldo123** and I do a Test it says:

**"Test connection failed of an error in initializing provider. Invalid authorization specification Invalid connection string attribute.”**

**"Error    1   Validation error. Migracion Connection manager "Base de Datos": SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'sa'.".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Invalid connection string attribute".      Migracion.dtsx  0   0"**

If I cut the **=** symbol the error change to other.

How I can mantain my password with equal sign?

Sorry for my bad English :P

Answer (score 1):

Myself can resolve it after hours. You might put the password in the **Properties box** in the right-button corner, and there put the password with double cuotes **"=naldo123"**, so **Visual Studio ETL** knows that the password contains specials symbols.